# how to add event reminder to my windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app in windows phone 7 where i need to add an event reminder. On clicking a button the reminder should be set. My cs file is:

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
public partial class EventDetails : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public EventDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
        ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;


        ApplicationBarIconButton home = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        home.IconUri = new Uri("/Image/icon_home_deselect.png", UriKind.Relative);
        home.Text = "Home";
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(home);
        home.Click += new EventHandler(home_Click);


        ApplicationBarIconButton share = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        share.IconUri = new Uri("/Image/icon_share_deselect.png", UriKind.Relative);
        share.Text = "Share";
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(share);
        share.Click += new EventHandler(share_Click);

        ApplicationBarIconButton news = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        news.IconUri = new Uri("Image/icon_news_deselect.png", UriKind.Relative);
        news.Text = "News";
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(news);
        news.Click += new EventHandler(news_Click);

        ApplicationBarIconButton events = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
        events.IconUri = new Uri("/Image/icon_event_deselect.png", UriKind.Relative);
        events.Text = "Video";
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(events);
        events.Click += new EventHandler(events_Click);
    }

    void events_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Events.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    void news_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/News.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    void share_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/share.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

    void home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void Image_Back(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Events.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var imagePath = "";
        var eventdate = "";
        var location = "";
        var utimee = "";
        var tzone = "";
        var ename = "";
        var desc = "";

        //check if particular parameter available in uri string
        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("image_path"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            imagePath = NavigationContext.QueryString["image_path"];

            eventimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/" + imagePath, UriKind.Absolute));


        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Time_Zone"))
        {
            tzone = NavigationContext.QueryString["Time_Zone"];
            timezone.Text = tzone;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("uTime"))
        {
            utimee = NavigationContext.QueryString["uTime"];
            utime.Text = utimee;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Event_Date"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            eventdate = NavigationContext.QueryString["Event_Date"];
            evntdate.Text = eventdate;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Location"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            location = NavigationContext.QueryString["Location"];
            loc.Text = location;
        }

        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Event_Name"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            ename = NavigationContext.QueryString["Event_Name"];
            enamee.Text = ename;
        }
        if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Event_Description"))
        {
            //if it is available, get parameter value
            desc = NavigationContext.QueryString["Event_Description"];
            edescription.Text = desc;
        }
```

}

```
    private void Image_Previous(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Events.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }



    private void Image_rem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterReminder();
    }

    private void RegisterReminder()
    {


        var reminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(ename) as Reminder ?? new Reminder(ename);
        reminder.Title = ename;
        reminder.Content = desc;
        // parse eventDate,utimee to beginDateTime
        reminder.BeginTime = beginDateTime;
        reminder.ExpirationTime = reminder.BeginTime.AddDays(1);
        reminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
        if (ScheduledActionService.Find(ename) == null)
            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
        else
            ScheduledActionService.Replace(reminder);
        MessageBox.Show("reminder set succeed!");


    }

}
```

}Now when the reminder button is clicked i want the fields utimee, tzone to be set and i get a pop up message "Event reminder added successfully"

I am not getting the idea on how to do this

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: what do yo mean by ' i want the fields utimee, tzone to be set and i get a pop up '?

Comment: @ChrisShao look when the reminder button will be clicked the data which i get from web service i.e date, time_zone and utime those should be set in my device and i should get a popup message that the reminder is set. m i able to make the thing clear?

Comment: Yes, you should set Title, Content, BeginTime, ExpirationTime and RecurrenceType in reminder by your data, after it, you can pop up a message.

Comment: @ChrisShao Can u please code it. I need to write code in the button click event.

Comment: @ChrisShao WHat should i write for title, content, id, begintime....The time zone and all i am getting from web service

Comment: Ok, I will code it several minutes later.

Comment: Hi, @user3156298, read my code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these steps:

1.get the values from webservice as global variable：

> eventDate,location, utimee, tzone, ename,desc.

2.click the reminder button, execute the click method

```
private void BtnReminderClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterReminder();
}
```

3.do reminder register

```
    private void RegisterReminder()
    {
        var reminder = ScheduledActionService.Find(ename) as Reminder ?? new Reminder(ename);
        reminder.Title = ename;
        reminder.Content = desc;
// parse eventDate,utimee to beginDateTime
        reminder.BeginTime = DateTime.Parse(eventDate).Date + DateTime.Parse(utimee).TimeOfDay;
        reminder.ExpirationTime = reminder.BeginTime.AddDays(1);
        reminder.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
        if (ScheduledActionService.Find(ename) == null)
           ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
        else
           ScheduledActionService.Replace(reminder);
       MessageBox.Show("reminder set succeed!");
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a few error: ename, desc, begindatetime doesnot exist in the current context

Comment: I see, you can set aname, desc eventDate, utimee as global variable. and beginDateTime is a DateTime type variable which can parse from eventDate and utimee.

Comment: I have set those global variables i.e., ename, desc, eventDate and utimee. Can u please parse that beginDateTime in your code

Comment: It worked fine. Thanks... Can u tell me 1 thing... is there any way to display the message box in the centre?

Comment: the default messageBox is on the top of screen. and it's the default syle of wp.